# How to install Eliom

Tags: ocaml, opam, ocsigen

I can't install eliom of the Ocsigen project

```
$ opam install eliom
Your request can't be satisfied:
  - No package matches eliom.
$ opam install eliom.5.0.0
Your request can't be satisfied:
  - No package matches eliom.5.0.0.
```

but surprisingly i can find the package with:

```
$ opam show eliom
             package: eliom
             version: 5.0.0
          repository: default
        upstream-url: https://github.com/ocsigen/eliom/archive/5.0.0.tar.gz
       upstream-kind: http
   upstream-checksum: dcd4c6b7b09a9ac233cb6db4605c233e
            homepage: http://ocsigen.org/eliom/
         bug-reports: https://github.com/ocsigen/eliom/issues/
            dev-repo: https://github.com/ocsigen/eliom.git
              author: dev@ocsigen.org
             license: LGPL-2.1 with OCaml linking exception
             depends: ocamlfind & camlp4 <= 4.02+6 & deriving >= 0.6 & (base-no-ppx | ppx_tools >= 0.99.3) & js_of_ocaml > 2.6 & tyxml > 3.5.0 & calendar & ocsigenserver >= 2.6 & ipaddr >= 2.1 & reactiveData >= 0.2 & base-bytes
   installed-version: 
  available-versions: 2.2.2, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 5.0.0
         description: Framework for programming Web sites and client/server Web applications.
```

what am i doing so wrong?

Comment: Please show `opam config report` when asking an opam related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should state:

- version of opam obtained by `opam --version`
- the current opam switch obtained by `opam switch`

The confusing message is a known issue of OPAM 1.2.2: https://github.com/ocaml/opam/issues/2526 .

My guess is that you are using OCaml 4.03.0.  You cannot meet the required conditions to install `eliom.5.0.0` with it.  According to `opam info eliom.5.0.0`, you need OCaml 4.02.x. See https://github.com/ocsigen/eliom/issues/324 for details.